# Basis and dimension of the span of the vectors (0, 0, 0), (9, 0, 0), (8, 1, 0), (1, 8, 9)

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Find a basis for the given subspace by deleting linearly dependent vectors.
$S = \text{span}\{(0, 0, 0), (9, 0, 0), (8, 1, 0), (1, 8, 9)\}$

I do not understand how to "delete linearly independent vectors" from the span. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: It is asking you to find a linearly independent subset of $S$ that has the same span as $S$.

Comment: If the first three are independent you can delete the fourth.  Find three that are independent and delete the fourth one.  There may be more than one answer.

Comment: If you're looking for a computation approach, you would use gaussian elimination on the matrix formed by using those vectors above as columns. Of course you want to discard the obvious vectors which are dependent first to save yourself on the computational work.

Comment: the zero vector is not going to do any good; so get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see pretty easily that $S = \Bbb R^3$. To do this, let $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3$. Then you can find $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$, such that 
$$(x,y,z) = a\cdot (0,0,0) + b \cdot(9,0,0) + c\cdot (8,1,0) + d \cdot (1,8,9) \; $$

Now we know that $\dim(\Bbb R^3) = \dim(S) = 3$. However, in your definition of $S$, $S$ is generated by 4 vectors. This means that you can remove one of them and the generated space of the remaining three vectors is still $S = \Bbb R^3$. So which vector can you remove, such that every $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3$ can still be written as a linear combination of the remaining three vectors?